# Web server on Ubuntu core 22

Tags: apache2, webserver, ubuntu-core, webapps, hosting

I started development for ubuntu core. I want to host my php web app on the ubuntu core. The problem is that it is snap based OS an I can't install apache2 and other packages what i need to host my webpage. Can you offer a snap to host php web apps or there is any way to install apache2 on Ubuntu core?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to install Docker, and then run the Webserver as a Docker container.

Comment: "Can you offer a snap to host php web apps or there is any way to install apache2 on Ubuntu core?" wrong place to ask; we are users just like you; if we could do this so could you :)

Comment: Ubuntu Core is targeted for IoT and embedded devices. Is there any particular reason why Ubuntu Server can't be used to host the site? 

Comment: @matigo It is a good way for me but i need to run gtk gui apl on the device and i tried to use ubuntu frame on ubuntu server. i installed it and run but i have no idea how to run a simple gnome-mastermind(find it in a ubuntu frame tutorisl) gtk app on the screen. When i try to run it i got error message: gtk cannot open display: . I tried a lot of options but i didn't find solution. The reason is why i dont use ubuntu desktop because a want to save resources.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1469346/edit) to add new information and improve your question. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Considering your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469373/ubuntu-frame-on-ubuntu-server), why don't you go forward with Ubuntu Frame on Ubuntu core right here?

Comment: Considering requirements from both questions, I don't see a GUI app and Apache2 running together on anything other than Ubuntu Desktop. Not Server, not Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ArturMeinild thank you for your recommendation. It seems the best way to use docker. I find some tutorials with which anyone can start to implement web-server on ubuntu core.
some help to start:

1. Download the Apache Image for Docker

   ```
   docker pull httpd
   ```
2. Start the Apache Container

   ```
   docker run -d --name [container-name] -p 80:[host-port] httpd 
   docker run -d --name apache -p 80:80 httpd
   ```
3. type this in your browser: `http://localhost:[host-port]`
4. to stop it

   ```
   docker stop [container-name-or-id]
   ```

thx for your answers.

Comment: Hi - you're encouraged to write up the solution in your answer rather than link to solutions on 3rd party sites. Those sites can go down and render your answer useless.