# Ubuntu-frame on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, gui, gtk

I installed ubuntu-frame on Ubuntu server, but when I tried to run a gtk GUI app (gnome-mastermind) then I got this error:

```
gtk cannot open display:
```

I followed these tutorials:

1. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/run-ubuntu-frame-on-your-device/29377
2. https://mir-server.io/docs/run-ubuntu-frame-on-your-desktop

I was setting `display:0` and `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0` but nothing helped.

Because the display was gray (ubuntu-frame default screen), I connected to it over ssh.

Why do I use Ubuntu server instead of Ubuntu core? Because I need to host my web app on apache but I need gui apps on the server.

And why not Ubuntu desktop? Because I want to save resources.

Comment: Well, the main difference between server and desktop is ... the lack of a "desktop" environment (GUI) on server. You should probably define your usecase more clearly, and research which tools you need. With the right tools, you can do *a lot* of things with Ubuntu server, without ever needing a GUI.

Comment: It seems you're backtracking from your previous question. Why don't you go forward with Ubuntu Frame on Ubuntu Core instead?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I am looking for the solutions paralell. if i got a solution then i will share it on both questions.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes you are right, but there is a minimal installation of ubuntu server and the ubuntu-frame need more less resources like the desktop. I tested the ubuntu core and the ubuntu server with minimal installation with ubuntu-frame and the ubuntu serever needed a bit less memory. that's what the difference, but on ubuntu server i can use apt package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. What did I do? I followed the tutorials in the question post.

```
ssh userName@[serverIpAddress]
sudo snap install ubuntu-frame
sudo snap set ubuntu-frame daemon=true
sudo snap run [gtkApp]
```

The 3rd step was the key to running a program (nowhere explains it)

`[gtkApp]` -> I tested it with `sudo snap install gnome-mines`.
It has to be snap.

Answer (score 0):

Is your GTK app packaged for use with Ubuntu Frame?

https://mir-server.io/docs/packaging-a-gtk3-application-as-an-iot-gui

If not, then maybe you need frame-it?

https://github.com/AlanGriffiths/frame-it